# Kotlin reflection error when calling function

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I was trying to cast an unknown given object to the required class using kotlin primitives conversion methods like this:

```
private fun callSelfParser(origObj: Any, destClazz: KClass<*>): Any {
        val methodName = when (destClazz) {
            Int::class -> "toInt"
            Char::class -> "toChar"
            Long::class -> "toLong"
            Byte::class -> "toByte"
            Float::class -> "toFloat"
            Short::class -> "toShort"
            Double::class -> "toDouble"
            Boolean::class -> "toBoolean"
            else -> ""
        }

        val parsingMethod: KFunction<*>
        try {
            parsingMethod = origObj::class.functions.toList().first { it ->
                it.name == methodName
            }
        } catch (e: NoSuchElementException) {
            throw ObjectMapperEx("Element $origObj doesn't have a method for parsing to $destClazz")
        }

        return parsingMethod.call(origObj)!!
    }
```

But I got the following exception when executing the .call():

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Reflection on built-in Kotlin types is not yet fully supported. No metadata found for public open val length: kotlin.Int defined in kotlin.String[DeserializedPropertyDescriptor@1cbb87f3]
```

Can someone say whats wrong or, if there's another way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Which version of kotlin are you using?

Comment: @jrtapsell 1.2.21

Comment: It looks like Kotlin can't use `.call` on extension functions. Because for `toString` it works fine. And why you search function in `destClass`?

Comment: @jrtapsell yes, it was wrong. But what's the alternative?